# Create Preference dynamically

Tags: java, android, xml

I am using this code to get a list of permission required by a specific application. I would like to create a Preference for each permission requested. How can I do this? The code is:

```
try {
        PackageInfo packageInfo = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(myPackageName, PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS);

        String[] requestedPermissions = packageInfo.requestedPermissions;
        if ( requestedPermissions != null ) {
            for (int i = 0; i < requestedPermissions.length; i++) {
                permission.setSummary(requestedPermissions[i] + "\n");
            }

        }
    }
    catch ( PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e ) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Add a preference for each permission ? What do you mean exactly ? What do you want to do ?

Comment: For example, if the application requires three permits I would like to have three Preference for each permit.

Comment: But what for exactly ?

Comment: Just set the preference key to `"Permit " + i` Where `i` is the variable in your loop?

Comment: What do you mean? I would like to create a Preference for each permit requested. What is not clear?

Comment: What you actually mean by permissions over here? Are they `uses-permission`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mario i ´d like to know for what are you going to create preferences with the name of App´s permissions, but here you got a solution.

```
try { 
        PackageInfo packageInfo = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(myPackageName, PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS);

        String[] requestedPermissions = packageInfo.requestedPermissions;
        if ( requestedPermissions != null ) {
            for (int i = 0; i < requestedPermissions.length; i++) {
              //permission.setSummary(requestedPermissions[i] + "\n");
              //method to create a preference with the name of your permission.  
              setPreference(this, requestedPermissions[i]);
            } 

        } 
    } 
    catch ( PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e ) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Method to create a preference .

```
public static void setPreference(Context context, String preferenceName)
{
    SharedPreferences settings = context.getSharedPreferences(preferenceName, 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
    //Add a key to this preference and his value.
    editor.putString(preferenceName+"_value", "Value stored in preference called: " + preferenceName);
    editor.commit();
}
```

create a method to read the value stored in your preferences

```
public static String getPreference(Context context,  String preferenceName){
            SharedPreferences settings = context.getSharedPreferences(preferenceName, 0);
            return settings.getString(preferenceName+"_value", "");
        }
```

then you can read values stored in your preferences, for example, read a value stored in a preference called

> "android.permission.INTERNET"

:

```
   Log.i("Preferences", getPreference(this,"android.permission.INTERNET"));
```

example Displayin data in Toast:

```
Toast.makeText(this, "the value stored in \"android.permission.INTERNET\" preference is: " + getPreference(this,"android.permission.INTERNET"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```